# Depth first search for a graph in C

Tags: c

I made the whole adjacency list representaion of graphs. I was able to implement BFS code as well. However, I am not able to understand DFS.

I have been able to come up with this algorithm:

1. Mark the source vertex as visited.
2. Push it on stack.
3. While stack is not empty
   {
   remove the vertex and name it as v.
   call dfs for all the neighbours of v.
   }

Is this correct? I want to do a complete traversal of the graph. There should be a base case as well in this, but what will it be?

Comment: This isn't really a question for SO, you just need to learn more about DFS. There's a pretty decent pseudocode and an explanation here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: But I read that, and that is what I am trying to say. There should be some base case of recursion. What will it be?

Comment: The base case is when the stack is empty.

Comment: And I was able to come up with that, that is what I wrote in my original post. But I know, there seems to be something missing there because there is no complete algo for recursive implementation of DFS.

Comment: Did you Google it? There's working code right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175108/graph-c-implementation-depth-first-search?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a visited array to keep track of all nodes that you have visited before.
And then avoid visiting the same nodes again and again.

This way your program will definitely terminate successfully